# Oracle substring select questions

Tags: oracle, select, substring, trim

Got stuck

```
select * 
from table a 
where ID like  'delr' || trim(substr(busns_asct_id,5)) || '%';
```

based on the above query, I get records like "delr112591-8218-1" but in that I need to eliminate ID like "delr60201-T,delr99999-A" and "delr1    -5"

How to eliminate this?

Comment: Please provide the exact pattern that you want to get, and the exact pattern that you want to exclude.

Comment: as @54l3d said, along with some sample data

Comment: Thanks. Based on my Query got 145 in that 22 records are like delr60201-T,delr99999-A  and one record is in delr1 -5. I need only 125 data like delr112591-8218-1 need to eliminate the 22 records which i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This how to deal with LIKE in Oracle:

- An underscore `_` in the pattern matches exactly one character
- A percent sign `%` in the pattern can match zero or more characters
- `ESCAPE '\'` to escape the `_` or `%` with any character you want, here I used `\`

To match `delr112591-8218-1` you can use that

```
like  'delr' || trim(substr(busns_asct_id,5)) || '-____-_';
```

any other string obtained by replacing `_` by any other character will match, so "delr60201-T","delr99999-A" and "delr1 -5" will not match, if you want something more accurate, you have to use REGEX.

[LIKE condition in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm)

[REGEX in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm)

Comment: Thanks. when i try to use the above query like  'delr' || trim(substr(busns_asct_id,5)) || '-____-_'; got only 5 records and i am not familiar with Regex any body help on this.

Comment: @Saravananv Check out the link above, Plz provide a complete literal description of the pattern so we can help you

Comment: `regexp_substr(busns_asct_id,'^delr(\d|-)+$')`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table a 
where ID like  'delr' || trim(substr(busns_asct_id,5)) || '-_' or ID like 'delr_-_;
```